# Creating Adjacency Matrix with Different Edge Probabilities

Tags: matlab, matrix, network-programming

I am creating an adjacency matrix that represents the following interactions. There are *m* communities and *n* agents belonging to each community. Each agent has a probability *p* of being linked to a member of his own community and a probability *q* of being linked to a member of another community. Each agent's position on the network is given by points x,y that are stored on two matrices X,Y both of size *m* by *n*. This was my first attempt but as you can see it has several mistakes.

```
ADJ=zeros(m*n); %Generates intraracial adjencecy matrix
losunos=randsample((n*m)^2,floor((n*m)^2*p)); %Generates edges according to p
ADJ(losunos)=1; %, ADJ(2,n+1)=1 if guy 2 from race 1 is connected to guy 1 from race 2
for k=1:m %Generates the edges
 for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if ADJ(i,j)==1
            plot([X(k,i) X(k,j)],[Y(k,i) Y(k,j)],'Color', colorstring(k))
        end
    end
 end
end
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

i think it works good already, you just forgot to keep the old lines when you draw a new one

```
%random values
m=5;
n=20;
p=0.7;
q=0.3;
X=randi(100,m,n);
Y=randi(100,m,n);
colorstring=['b';'r';'g';'c';'k'];

ADJ=zeros(m*n); %Generates intraracial adjencecy matrix
losunos=randsample((n*m)^2,floor((n*m)^2*p)); %Generates edges according to p
ADJ(losunos)=1; %, ADJ(2,n+1)=1 if guy 2 from race 1 is connected to guy 1 from race 2
figure; %create figure
hold on %keep old plots while making new ones
for k=1:m %Generates the edges
 for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if ADJ(i,j)==1
            plot([X(k,i) X(k,j)],[Y(k,i) Y(k,j)],'Color', colorstring(k))
        end
    end
 end
end
hold off %back to standard
```